# Audio issue when HDMI drawing tablet is connected?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, hdmi, error

I'm running a 13" Macbook pro 2017 with operating system Mojave 10.14.4.

I have an HDMI connected tablet (Huion Gt-220). When I connect my drawing tablet to my computer, it locks out my sound for the computer.

I've tried going into System Preferences and changing the output to internal speakers. I've gone into the Audio MIDI setup and tried to configure it from there as well.

In the audio MIDI setup I've also tried making a multi output and an aggregated device.

I've tried it with and without headphones. I can't get it to work for the life of me. Does anyone else have any ideas on how to fix this? I'm dying here because I'll need to watch/listen to classes at the same time as I work and I can't seem to set it up.

Comment: If that advice worked for you, please accept it so the post can be closed otherwise it keeps coming back like a bad penny.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Facebook Huion Thread

I found a thread with your issue on the Huion facebook page. They suggested there trying to re-install the drivers for this particular device there. [The thread](https://www.facebook.com/huion/posts/hi-i-connect-a-hdmi-cable-to-the-huion-gt220-and-when-i-play-a-video-on-my-macbo/1654213994798053/).

This was the verbatim from the support person in the thread:

> Huion Cerine Oshiro
>
> Please try to reinstall the driver from our website to see if it
>   helps: https://www.huiontablet.com/support/ Here's a step by step to
>   reinstall, please try and see if it works:
>
> (If you are using Mac system, please skip 3-4 steps）
>
> 1. Log out the Huion driver, close all drawing programs you are running, close your anti virus software.
> 2. Uninstall the Huion driver from control panel.
> 3. Find the `TabletDriver` folder from `C:\Program files\` and delete it. (If you are not able to find this folder, that means you have
>      deleted it already, and you may skip this step.)
> 4. Go to `C:\windows\system32` or `C:\windows\system64`, find `wintab32.dll` and delete it.
> 5. Unplug the USB cable.
> 6. Download driver from Huion website and install it as an Administrator.
> 7. Reboot the computer and wait until it finishes rebooting.
> 8. Plug the tablet back in. If the problem still persists, please send your problem to:service@huiontablet.com to get instant technical
>      support, thank you!

#### 2. DeviantArt Thread

I also found another thread mentioning a prior version of a Huion device, Huion GT-185 HD. This is a tablet monitor which I assume is the same type of item as your [Huion Gt-220](https://www.huiontablet.com/huion-gt-220-v2-199.html).  The thread was on [DeviantArt page for the GT-185 HD device](https://www.deviantart.com/huion/art/Huion-GT-185-HD-1-528769581).

In the thread a Huion support staff made the point that these tablet monitors do not include audio.

> huion Oct 20, 2017 
>   Hello,
>
> Kindly note that there is no audio device in the monitor, so it can
>   not give off any audio.

They then went on to suggest that the ordering of the displays mattered because of this fact.

> huion Oct 23, 2017  Hello,
>
> Yes, it supports extended mode. Kindly inform you that if you want to
>   use the monitor in extend mode and then use the pen on the HUION
>   monitor, you need to go to control panel to identify Huion monitor is
>   recognized by which monitor in your system. For instance, if GT-185HD
>   is monitor 2 in your system, please select Monitor 2 in the driver. If
>   you have selected Monitor 2, but you still couldn't use the pen on it,
>   please try to select "all desktop area".

Comment: I had to uninstall and reinstall 4 times, but it's working now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Sparkles - that's great news. Can you please mark this as accepted so everyone knows your issue's been resolved? Thanks for the Q and good luck w/ the device.